# React setState and array.push not working

Tags: reactjs

This is a simple memory game. There is an array of cards on the page if the user clicks the same picture twice the game gets over. Everything works perfectly except when I add setState the array.push stops pushing the new item in the array.

````
const Main = () => {
    
//initial array which I map
    const [picArray, setPicArray]= useState([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
     let userArray = [];
      
    //everytime picture is clicked array is shuffled
    const shufflePicArray = () =>{
        return picArray.sort( () => Math.random() - 0.5)
    }

//onclick
    const handleClick = (id) =>{
        let matchedEl = userArray.find(el => el == picArray[id])
   
        if(matchedEl){
            alert('game finished')
            userArray = [];
        } else {
            userArray.push(picArray[id])
            let shuffledArray = shufflePicArray();
        //if I skip this setState, then the item gets pushed in the userArray. If I keep the setState, then items don't get pushed in the array and I see only one item in the array like the setState regrshed the userArray. Here suffledarray has nothing to do with userArray.
         **setPicArray([...shuffledArray])** 
        }
        
    }```

help please!
````

Comment: Seems like `userArray` should be state so it persists between renders, no?

Comment: when you `setState` the component re-renders. And you do `let userArray = [];` so after a render you are with an empty `userArray`.

Comment: I suggest you keep in state a "guess 1" and a "guess 2", and use an effect to reset when both "guess" states are populated and you check for match.

Comment: Don't use array.push with state in react as it mutates the state. Use non mutating array methods on state, so use the spread notation like `newUserArray = [...userArray, picArray[id]]`

Comment: thank you so much!. something new I learned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the spread syntax so that it considers your original state and the element that you're adding to that state like this `newUserArray = [...userArray, picArray[id]]` and then `setState({newUserArray})`